# Why doesn't Brave resolve DNS rewrites?

Tags: linux, windows, dns, browser, flatpak

I have set up AdGuard Home and pointed my router to the AGH instance in order to block ads etc.

I have created a couple of DNS rewrites so that I enter an address to my liking and one of these is `homeserv.local` -> `192.168.0.40`. Now, there seems to be an issue, in Brave only, where entering `homeserv.local` does not resolve; it spits out the following:

```
This site can’t be reached
homeserv.local’s DNS address could not be found. Diagnosing the problem.
DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE
```

The odd part is that using browsers other than Brave work, across different machines. E.g. if I enter `homeserv.local` into Firefox on my machine (Linux), it works; same goes for my wife's machine, where she uses Windows - both on Firefox and Edge.

It doesn't seem to be an issue confined to Brave on my Linux box, as trying the same on Brave on my Android cellphone spits out the same error.

I've tried disabling `Always use secure connections` and both editing and/or disabling `Use secure DNS` in Brave, but that didn't solve it, either.

Fedora Linux 37; Brave Browser (Flatpak) - Latest.

Comment: Likely when the name doesn't resolve, brave or your device is not using your dns server, but some external dns server like google's dns.

Comment: @telcoM You are absolutely right! That was the issue. You're more than welcome to post it as an answer, and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two-part names ending in `.local` are now reserved for mDNS (multicast DNS) instead of regular DNS, which may cause surprises; perhaps the `hosts:` line of your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` includes one of the `mdns*` options before `dns` or `resolve`?

Or maybe Brave has a built-in exception for it, for the same reason? The officially recommended domain suffix for private home networks seems to be `.home.arpa`.

mDNS was first proposed back in year 2000, and a specification in the form of [RFC 6762](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762.html) was published in year 2013, and the recommendation to use `.home.arpa` was in [RFC 8375](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8375.html) of May 2018.

mDNS is one part of the *zero-configuration networking* concept, that will enable e.g. a group of laptop users to form an ad-hoc network where the computers will be able to find each other and share information using human-friendly hostnames instead of using raw IP (or IPv6) addresses. It is implemented in Linux by the Avahi tools and now also by `systemd-resolved`, and in MacOS and other Apple products it is known as Bonjour.

Comment: How long has this been the case, if you know?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks!